# Using ClangTool to parse a string

Tags: clang

The following code successfully sets up a ClangTool for parsing:

```
std::vector<std::string> source_files;
cl::OptionCategory option_category("options");
CommonOptionsParser options_parser(argc, argv, option_category);
ClangTool tool(options_parser.getCompilations(), source_files);
```

However, I created argc and argv on my own -- they didn't come from main().  Instead of an input file, is it possible to get the ClangTool to parse the contents of a string?  E.g.,

```
const char *str = "extern int foo;\n";
```

mapVirtualFile() looked like what I wanted, but when I tried, foo didn't come out of it.

```
tool.mapVirtualFile(StringRef("faux_file.c"), StringRef(str));
// Then proceed to tool.run(...), etc.
```

I could create a temporary file in /tmp, but I'd like to simply read from the string.

**Update:**

Creating a temporary file works.  It's kind of hack-ish, but it's stable and consistent.  It would be nice to have a way of inputting from a string, but it doesn't seem possible with the existing implementation.